# What is the correct configuration AWS SageMaker-Python-SDK to achieve local debugging/training with Apple M1 Pro

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-debugger

I want to run an RL training job on AWS SageMaker(script given below). But since the project is complex I was hoping to do a test run using SageMaker Local Mode (In my M1 MacBook Pro) before submitting to paid instances. However, I am struggling to make this local run successful even with a simple training task.

Now I did use Tensorflow-metal and Tensorflow-macos when running local training jobs(Without SageMaker). And I did not see anywhere I can specify this in the `framework_version` and nor that I am sure `"local_gpu"` which is the correct argument for a normal linux machine with GPU is exactly matching for Apple Silicon (M1 Pro).

I searched all over but I cannot find a case where this is addressed. (Very odd, am I doing something wrong? If so, please correct me.) If not and there's anyone who knows of a configuration, a docker image or an example properly done with M1 Pro please share.

I tried to run the following code. Which hangs after Logging in. (If you are trying to run the code, try with any simple training script as entry_point, and make sure to login with a similar code matching to your region using awscli with following command.
`aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

```
##main.py
import boto3
import sagemaker
import os
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlow

sess = sagemaker.Session() 
#role = <'arn:aws:iam::0000000000000:role/CFN-SM-IM-Lambda-Catalog-sk-SageMakerExecutionRole-BlaBlaBla'> #KINDLY ADD YOUR ROLE HERE

(x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

os.makedirs("./data", exist_ok = True)

np.savez('./data/training', image=x_train, label=y_train)
np.savez('./data/validation', image=x_val, label=y_val)

# Train on local data. S3 URIs would work too.
training_input_path   = 'file://data/training.npz'
validation_input_path = 'file://data/validation.npz'

# Store model locally. A S3 URI would work too.
output_path           = 'file:///tmp/model/'

tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='mnist_keras_tf.py',
                          role=role,
                          instance_count=1, 
                          instance_type='local_gpu',   # Train on the local CPU ('local_gpu' if it has a GPU)
                          framework_version='2.1.0',
                          py_version='py3',
                          hyperparameters={'epochs': 1},
                          output_path=output_path
                         )

tf_estimator.fit({'training': training_input_path, 'validation': validation_input_path})
```

Comment: I don't think there's a 'local_gpu' option for instance type, you'd simply specify 'local'. Have you tried that, and does it work?

Comment: Hi, @durga_sury Thank you for the comment. And yes, I did try that ends up saying there is no GPU found. I believe this is because local_gpu is created to accommodate Nvidia GPUs.

Answer (score 6):

The [prebuilt SageMaker Docker Images for Deep Learning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/pre-built-containers-frameworks-deep-learning.html) doesn't have Arm based support yet.
You can see Available Deep Learning Containers Images [here](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/available_images.md).

The solution is to build your own Docker image and use it with SageMaker.

This is an example `Dockerfile` that uses `miniconda` to install TensorFlow dependencies:

```
FROM arm64v8/ubuntu

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         wget \
         nginx \
         ca-certificates \
         gcc \
         linux-headers-generic \
         libc-dev

RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh
RUN chmod a+x Miniconda3-py38_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh
RUN bash Miniconda3-py38_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh -b
ENV PATH /root/miniconda3/bin/:$PATH

COPY ml-dependencies.yml ./
RUN conda env create -f ml-dependencies.yml

ENV PATH /root/miniconda3/envs/ml-dependencies/bin:$PATH
```

This is the the `ml-dependencies.yml`:

```
name: ml-dependencies
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - numpy
  - pandas
  - scikit-learn
  - tensorflow==2.8.2
  - pip
  - pip:
    - sagemaker-training
```

And this is how you'll run the trainin gusing SageMaker Script mode:

```
    image = 'sagemaker-tensorflow2-graviton-training-toolkit-local'

    california_housing_estimator = Estimator(
        image_uri=image,
        entry_point='california_housing_tf2.py',
        source_dir='code',
        role=DUMMY_IAM_ROLE,
        instance_count=1,
        instance_type='local',
        hyperparameters={'epochs': 10,
                         'batch_size': 64,
                         'learning_rate': 0.1})

    inputs = {'train': 'file://./data/train', 'test': 'file://./data/test'}
    california_housing_estimator.fit(inputs, logs=True)
```

You can find the full working sample code on the Amazon SageMaker Local Mode Examples GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-local-mode/tree/main/tensorflow_graviton_bring_your_own_california_housing_local_training_toolkit).

Comment: Thank you, I already stumbled upon this path. But it's really nice to have it validated. Appreciate it. Also, there are too many unknown, unanswered problems in the subject. I'd like to keep a thread open. :)